# Anyway to get more info on how Cloud9 connects via ssh

Tags: ssh, cloud9-ide, digital-ocean

Trying to connect Cloud9 to my Digital Ocean droplet and I'm getting:

> Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server

I've added the ssh public key into my .ssh/authorized_keys file and I know I can connect via ssh. Is there any way to get more info than just that is can't connect?

David

Answer (score 2):

You need to add public key from your profile to .ssh/authorized_keys (*not `hosts`*) and make sure that .ssh/authorized_keys file belongs to you and have can be read written only by the owner (should say `-rw-------` when doing `ls -la ~/.ssh`)

Comment: Hi thanks allot for answering ! I still can't log in via ssh:       -rw-------  1 root      root      1144 Jul 28 07:15 authorized_keys  Is there anything else I can see as to why it can't connect ?

Comment: Sorry, yes I just tried and I still get: Cloud9 couldn't connect to SSH server root@*******. Maybe I should contact Cloud 9 support but there website is a bit confusing.

Comment: Indeed, the support website is https://c9.io/support/ and it have an email link to support@c9.io. Try using that link.

Answer (score 2):

To get a bit more info, you can try SSHing into your server from one of your other Cloud9 workspaces. Since your Cloud9 SSH key is the same across all workspaces, you'll be able to check if your key has been properly added to the server this way.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. It turns out ssh is really finicky with permissions I had to sort them out on my server then it work but thanks for the advice on how to debug :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to figure out how to get more info on this but I was able to figure out that it was permissions on the .ssh/authorized_keys file / directory. Thanks again for all the help

David

Answer (score 1):

Just finished chatting with cloud9 support and got this working.  It's important to note that there are THREE items that require specific permissions:

- you user home folder (~) folder should be drwxr-xr-x
- your ~/.ssh folder should be drwx------
- your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys folder should be -rw-------

Comment: also, you can view C9 access attempts by tailing /var/log/auth.log

Answer (score 0):

Here's in my case

- check your instance security groups and ACL
- check your sshd_config, ssh, and PAM auth (default is fine, but in my case I mistakenly set `PubKeyAuthentication to No`), I tried to mimic the ssh connection with `ssh -vvv user@ip_address` from another server (after putting the public key in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file), make sure it's `-rw-------`
- check for the files and folders permission, especially in the ~/.ssh folder
- check incoming connection errors in `/var/log/auth.log`
- check for node js if it's installed
- put the node path (use `which node` command)